# Reward Video Against Google Admob Privacy Policy?

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

I want to know if i put an ad reward video in app but without getting any reward after user watching it .. Just like interstitial ads or banner ads.. so is this step against google admob privacy policy?

Comment: You are not forced to give 'rewards' to user. Google just used the term 'reward' here as an example. Here is the first line from their rewarded video policy: "Rewards from rewarded ads are transacted solely between the publisher and the user. Google does not grant or verify any rewards."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal advice.